# Verify that $\lim _{n \to \infty } \sqrt n (1-a^2)^n=0$, $a \in [0,1 ]$

Tags: calculus

With the possibility that this is a duplicate, how can I verify the following limit?

$$\lim _{n \to \infty } \sqrt n (1-a^2)^n=0$$, $a \in [0,1 ]$

I tried l'Hopitals rule but that only gave me a new expression involving the square root of $n $ times an expression to the power of $n $, giving the indeterminate form $\infty 0 $.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't hold for $a=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your limit is false for $a = 0$, and trivial for $a=1$, so I will assume $a\in(0,1).$

Define $\alpha = \frac{1}{1-a^2}$, then $\alpha \geq 1$. Now, rewrite your limit as $$\frac{\sqrt n}{\alpha^n}$$ and either use L'Hospital directly or, even better, first use the estimation $$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\alpha^n} < \frac{n}{\alpha^n}$$
and then use the rule.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still not getting it...

$D(\frac {n } {\alpha ^n })=\frac { 1} {\alpha ^n }-\frac {n ln \alpha } {\alpha ^n }  $

And the limit of $\frac {n ln \alpha } {\alpha ^n }$ is again of the form $\infty 0 $, right?

Comment: @Alexander You may have missed exactly what L'Hospital's rule says. It does not say that the limit of $f(x)$ is equal to the limit of $f'(x)$, it says something else. What does it say?

Comment: Thanks, I have't used the rule for a while...

Comment: @Alexander My pleasure. It happens.